# Plotting Smooth rainfall map for Trinidad and Tobago

Tags: r, maps

I created a Rainfall Map for Trinidad using data from World Climate. However, the maps is not smooth. I would like to know how to get a smooth map. I have attached my code along with the map. Any help would be appreciated.

```
library(dplyr)
library(tidyr)
library(sp)
library(ggplot2)
library(rgeos)
library(maptools)
library(rgdal)
library(raster)
library(rasterVis)  #visualization library for raster

TT=getData('GADM', country='Trinidad and Tobago', level=1)
plot(TT) # this can be a little slow

clim=getData('worldclim', var='bio', res=2.5) 
clim

gain(clim)=0.1 
plot(clim[[12]])
 
gplot(clim[[12]])+geom_raster(aes(fill=value))+
  facet_wrap(~variable)+
  scale_fill_gradientn(colours=c("brown", "red", "yellow", "darkgreen", "green"),trans="log10") +
  coord_equal() 

## crop to a latitude/longitude box
r1 <- crop(clim[[12]], extent(-62,-60,10,12)) 
## Crop using a Spatial polygon 
r1 <- crop(clim[[12]], bbox(TT))

plot(r1)
```

Answer (score 1):

Your data:

```
library(raster)
TT <- getData('GADM', country='Trinidad and Tobago', level=1)
clim <- getData('worldclim', var='bio', res=2.5) 
r <- crop(clim[[12]], TT)
```

Solution:

```
x <- disaggregate(r, 5, method="bilinear")
y <- mask(x, TT)
plot(y)
```